# atlbase.h and different versions of VC CRT

Tags: c++, c++-cli, atl, crt

I have a C++/CLI project created with Visual Studio 2010 that targets .NET Framework 3.5 and PlatformToolset v90. Initially it requests the VC CRT of version 9.0.21022.8, but if I include atlbase.h header then it requests the VC CRT of version 9.0.30729.6161.
Why does this happen? And how can I make it to target 9.0.30729.6161 without including atlbase.h?

I tried to define macroses _BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION=1 and _BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION=1 but this didn't help.

Comment: Why on earth do you need ATL if you're using C++/CLI ? Either do COM (and use ATL, and normal C++), or .NET. Don't do both, this is asking for trouble.

Comment: I don't need ATL, I need target 9.0.30729.6161. But I can accomplish this only by including atlbase.h. So question is how can I get rid of atlbase.h but still targeting 9.0.30729.6161?

Comment: You must have VS2008 installed to do target V9.0. Make sure that you have the SP1 for VS2008. Uninstalling + reinstalling everything should fix it (I never had such problems). It works with VC++2008 express in case you don't want to pay for 2 licenses.

Comment: I do have VS2008 with SP1. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version is set by vc/include/crtassem.h, near the bottom you can see:

```
#ifndef _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION
#if _BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION
#define _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "9.0.30729.6161"
#else
#define _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "9.0.21022.8"
#endif
#endif
```

So the rule is that you can explicitly override the version by #defining _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION.  Don't do that.  As you noted in your question, #defining _BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION to 1 gets you the version string you want.

Having a problem with this in a C++/CLI project is possible.  You can compile C++/CLI code without ever #including any of the CRT include files.  So you'll end up with a default version which, ironically, is defaulted by the *linker* to its own version of the CRT.  So a workaround is to explicitly put `#include <crtassem.h>` in one of your source code files.  #including atlbase.h would do that too since it *does* include CRT headers but of course is the big hammer approach.

Additional troubleshooting is available from Project + Properties, C/C++, Advanced, Show Includes = Yes.  You'll see a trace of all the #include files getting included in the Output window.

Beware that you'll now have the additional burden to ensure that the up-to-date version of msvcr90.dll gets deployed on the user's machine.  Your program will fail to start if it is missing or old.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. My application uses CRT as private assembly that is always of version 9.0.30729.6161. Given that would it be the right approach to explicitly #define _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "9.0.30729.6161"?

Comment: The crtassem.h file as well as (hopefully) whatever copy you use of the DLL on your dev machine can get updated by a security patch.  This already happened a couple of times.  And that's how you ended up with .6161 in your copy.  So no, #defining it yourself isn't a good idea, the security patch isn't going to update that.